# Changes in underlying List<Entry> not showing in the parent map object?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    myMap.put("a", 1);
    myMap.put("b", 7);
    myMap.put("c", 2);
    myMap.put("b", 5);

    List<Entry<String, Integer>> myList = mySort(myMap); //sort by map values!
    //myList is now sorted but myMap is not!
}

public List<Entry<String,Integer>> mySort(Map<String, Integer> map){        
    Set<Entry<String,Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(set);       
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>()
    {
        public int compare(Entry<String,Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2){
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
           }    
     }
    );      
    return list;        
}
```

My question is - after I call the sort (in the last line of main function), if I print my list, I see it sorted all right.  But what would happen to `myMap` - if I check it, I still find it unsorted! Since the list has been created by "copy by reference" from the entity set of the map, shouldn't the changes in list reflect upon the map as well?

Comment: What is `map` in `mySort(map);`

Comment: sorry for the type. fixed it now.

Comment: @Tintin oh gosh, did you just retyped all that text instead of copy-pasting? :)

Comment: No I did copy paste but removed a whole lot of other application code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the list has been created by "copy by reference" from the entity set of the map, shouldn;t be the changes in list reflect upon the map as well?

In a word - no.

The list holds the same references as the entry set, but is a different object. Changing the list (such as sorting it, adding or removing elements) will **not** affect the entry set. However, if you access a specific entry via the list and modify it, you'll observe the entry in the map has also been modified, since, as you noted, both the list and the map hold **the same reference**.

Comment: Where are these sorted objects of the list getting stored?  As you said they should be the same objects as of map... isn't it?  Then where is this "sorted" metadata information (if there is such thing) getting stored? Thanks.

Comment: Does the iteration implementaiton of HashMap rely on the order of the Entry set? When you sort the Entry set, does it guarantee that the Map will always be iterated in order?

Comment: @Tintin - the `ArrayList` stores its own order. The entries inside it have nothing to do with the order they are stored in, be it sorted or not.

Comment: great.  this, I didn't know!  Is it same for all the other collection classes as well?

Comment: @Tintin unless you implement your own funky collection, yes - storing an object in a (standard) collection does not change the object in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
List<Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(set);
```

You are creating a new `List` with the same elements that an original set contained and sort it. But you are sorting the new list, not the original set.

Also, what are you trying to achieve? The `Set` is not required to hold elements order, so you can't really sort a `Map` keys. You could use a `LinkedHashMap` - it stores iteration order.